# How do you tell if a Google Sheet has script attached or not?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

Is it possible to know, programmatically, whether a Google Sheets document has a script object attached?

After finding that out, I'm also interesting in knowing what properties can be discovered about the attached script and whether permissions for it can be discovered and defined?

The [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata) on developerMetadata looks like a place one might start.

Comment: I pretty sure this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately what you want cannot be achieved as there is no way to check if a spreadsheet has a script attached to it.**

The only way to check if a spreadsheet and a script are bound together is the other way around: by checking from a script if there is any spreadsheet attached to it.

This can be done by using the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` method.

As for the `developerMetadata`, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata), this simply refers to the data from the spreadsheet itself associated with the developer metadata and has nothing to do with any scripts bound to it.

> Developer metadata may be used to associate arbitrary data with various parts of a spreadsheet and will remain associated at those locations as they move around and the spreadsheet is edited. For example, if developer metadata is associated with row 5 and another row is then subsequently inserted above row 5, that original metadata will still be associated with the row it was first associated with (what is now row 6). If the associated object is deleted its metadata is deleted too.

It is also important to note that the script bound to the spreadsheet is not an object, therefore you cannot retrieve it.

**What you can do in this situation however, is to file a feature request for the Sheets API following the link [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917) and don't forget to include all the details that might be needed for this.**